# How to blank a People Picker?

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have an spfx form on a SharePoint Online site collection which reads/writes data to an SP list.

I have 3 people pickers which I've managed to submit (using a submit button) successfully to the list. I can also retrieve these 3 people pickers from the list successfully.

The problem is when I remove a user from any of the people pickers. The console gives me an error of Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference.

I think I need something that can handle the removal of a user in the function but I can't think what.
I subsequently want the user (using the form) to be able to remove the user from the PP and then click an update button to update and submit the change.

Here's 1 of the 3 people pickers in the render:

```
 <PeoplePicker
         context={this.props.context}
         personSelectionLimit={1}
         groupName={''} // Leave this blank in case you want to filter from all users
         showtooltip={false}
         isRequired={false}
         disabled={false}
         selectedItems={this._deptContGetPeoplePickerItems}//This is the 'onChange'
         showHiddenInUI={false}
         defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.DeptContactPPDefaultItems ? this.state.DeptContactPPDefaultItems : []}//this is the value it means if this.state.PeoplePickerDefaultItems is truthy then show it, if not then don't
         principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
         resolveDelay={1000}
         ensureUser={true}
    />
```

Here are the 3 (1 per PP) functions for all 3 of the people pickers. These functions are assigned (as you can see above) to the selectedItems property of the PP. I believe this is the 'onChange' property of the PP:

```
 private _deptContGetPeoplePickerItems(items) {
    if(items !== null && items.length >0){
    this.setState({
      DeptContact: items[0].id,
      DeptContactPPDefaultItems: [items[0].secondaryText],

    }
}

      console.log(this.state.DeptContactPPDefaultItems+'this.state.DeptContactPPDefaultItemsADD');
    });
   } 
   if(items !== null && items.length >0){
     this.setState({
      DeptContact: items[0].id,
      DeptContactPPDefaultItems: [items[0].secondaryText]  
     }

     });
   }
  }
```

As you can see I've attempted to handle removal of a user from the PP with the if. I seem to think a lot can be handled with if's!

As I've mentioned above, it says 'Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference' when I remove a user from the PP. This error happens when I actually click the remove x on the PP, not during submission or update btw.

Anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, but this: `if (items === null) { this.setState({ LinkAdviser: items[0].id, ...` is clearly not going to do anything un-errorful.

Comment: Yes, that's now changed. I think blanking the people picker doesn't update the state. How would I target such an event?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the clue, I've figured it out with some help. The issue was that the if's weren't considering that the 'items' were an array, and so I added if(items !== null && items.length > 0){
Code has been edited to reflect the successful change.